# Defining a custom rgb map for creating a color scheme?

Tags: terminal, colorscheme

Please excuse my ignorance, I'm probably missing something pretty fundamental here in regards to how 256 color terminals actually work with vim.

I'm trying to create a custom color scheme for vim and upon looking at the source of some existing color schemes such as [seoul256](https://github.com/junegunn/seoul256.vim/blob/master/colors/seoul256.vim) and [badwolf](https://github.com/sjl/badwolf/blob/master/colors/badwolf.vim), I notice that they are defining their own custom color palettes that are not a part of the standard 256 colors. I was under the impression that the colors available are confined to the [256 terminal colors?](http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html)

Are they simply overriding the default colors? Am I able to replace any 8-bit addressable color with my own arbitrary ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `s:rgb_map` in seoul256 and all the `s:bwc.*` in badwolf do not define colors outside of the xterm palette. Rather, they are just there to *map* the finely-tuned hexadecimal colors used in GUI Vim with their closest equivalent in the xterm palette used in color terminals.

Taking seoul256 as an example, `#999872` will be used for some highlight groups in GVim/MacVim while the similar but slightly darker `101` (`#87875f`) will be used for the same highlight groups in Vim.

Such compromises are *very* commonplace in the colorscheme business. If you don't like that, I see four "solutions" which all come with their own issues and compromises:

### Choose all your colors from the xterm palette

This is the path I chose when I started work on [my own colorscheme](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice). The good side is that your colorscheme is more or less guaranteed to look the same in Vim *and* GVim but you will soon find out that the xterm palette has *many* shortcomings (no browns, dark colors too intense…) that will restrict your creativity.

### Ask your users to change their xterm palette

Programs like [colorcoke](https://github.com/trapd00r/colorcoke) let you change the xterm palette in [many crazy ways](https://github.com/trapd00r/colorcoke/wiki). If using a very specific palette is an important part of your concept you can make that program — or some script that you generated with it — part of the requirements for installing/using your colorscheme.

### Target custom builds or Neovim running in a handful of terminal emulators

You can patch Vim so that it can use the `rgb(00,00,00)` notation in the [terminal emulators that support that feature](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728). [That patch](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/commits/branch/24-bit-xterm) recently found its way in Neovim so that could be another option for you.

### Build your colorscheme for 16 colors terminal emulators

…and give your users a ready made palette for customizing their terminal emulator.

### So…

My preference goes to the first process because all the others have too many requirements and dependencies that make installation and support too hard.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation, that clears up a lot of my confusions. By the way, I discovered Apprentice while browsing for color schemes a few weeks ago, and its one of my favorites!

Comment: Note that you can write your colorscheme in such a way to use RGB colors when available (gVim, xterm customized palette), but fall back to the standard xterm colours if that's not available. [Solarized does this](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/blob/master/colors/solarized.vim#L243) for example. You can eat your cake and have it too!